# Donut polygons getting filled when exporting to 3d Web Scene

Tags: 3d, cityengine, web-scene

I have built a model using ArcScene by draping 2D polygon data over an elevation raster and am having issues when using the Export to 3D Web Scene tool.  The tool builds the model successfully, but when I view the model using the CityEngine web viewer the center of donut polygons get filled with gray which ends up covering the interior polygons.  See images below for an example of what I am talking about.  If I cut the donut polygon into two then the issue goes away, however this isn't really feasible to do for my entire model.  I am hoping that someone may have a suggestion of a tool or setting that I should try.  I am new to the 3D mapping world so please bear with me.

[image]

Here is what is being hidden by the darker gray "filled" donut hole.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To drape polygons over terrain is extremely difficult task, no wonder sometimes ArcScene fails to do so.

You can help it by splitting complex polygons into basic triangles. This [Cutting rectangle set (not squares) into triangles using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142334/cutting-rectangle-set-not-squares-into-triangles-using-arcgis-for-desktop/142336#142336) will give you idea on automation of the process