# How to create points along a polygon within a maximum distance from each other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, point-in-polygon, proximity

I'm looking for a tool that generate points within a polygon with a fixed-distance between point neighbors.

I've tried [Create Random Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm), but the parameter is only minimum distance, and I was looking for a maximum distance or fixed-distance.

[Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) works well with the distance between neighbors up/down/right/left, but not between other neighbors.

For now I'm manually creating buffers and moving them around to cover the entire area, but I belief there would be an automated way to do it.

Any ideas?

I'm currently working with ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because it asks for solutions using any of three GIS software products which makes it effectively three broad questions.  Once you decide on the GIS software that you will be using we need you to tell us not just what you want to do, but what you have tried and where you are stuck.  It currently reads like an assignment.

Comment: It could be also a question about finding a single method. Hexbinning could be one well supported alternative https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/25/hexbinning/

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185889/arcmap-fill-polygon-with-points-highest-possible-number-bin-packing-problem/186025#186025

Comment: @PolyGeo I found it hard to explain the tool I was looking for without the real-life example, especially when this is not my native-language. It's not an assignment at all though, I just need a tool that creates points within a predefined distance between the neighbors. Because it's a hard tool to find I would'nt mind using other software, that's all.

Comment: @dbaston, user30184 thanks for the helpful input :)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you want it to look like? It seems that you might be interested in this hexagon tessellation tool: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03388990d3274160afe240ac54763e57