# Offset regular point grid inside polygon by a defined angle from north

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon

Is there anyway to fill an irregular polygon with regular points but to also offset this regular point pattern with a defined angle offset from north? I make reference to an older answered post regarding the filling of polygons

[Filling polygons with points or polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216303/filling-polygons-with-points-or-polygons)

Comment: is this for cartographic reasons (to do stippling) or do you actually need the points e.g. to do sampling?

Comment: The points are representative of a wind turbine points within an array. so i would like to adjust the angle of the points to a defined value or another layer attribute  value

Comment: @user95443 any news about the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may run this code (adapted from [this](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/10/30/how-to-generate-regularly-spaced-points-in-qgis-using-python/) post I wrote some time ago) from the **Python Console** for controlling the spacing of your points and the inset from the North:

```py
from qgis.core import *

# Set the spacing
spacing = 10
# Set the inset
inset_x = 5
inset_y = 5

# Get the Coordinate Reference System and the extent from the loaded layer
layer = iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
ext=layer.extent()

# Create a new vector point layer
points_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=' + crs, 'grid', "memory")
prov = points_layer.dataProvider()

# Create the coordinates of the points in the grid
points = []

for ft in layer.getFeatures():
    feat_geom = ft.geometry()
    # Set the extent of the new layer
    xmin = ext.xMinimum() + inset_x
    xmax = ext.xMaximum()
    ymin = ext.yMinimum()
    ymax = ext.yMaximum() - inset_y
    y = ymax
    while y >= ymin:
        x = xmin
        while x <= xmax:
            geom = QgsGeometry().fromPoint(QgsPoint(x, y))
            feat = QgsFeature()
            point = QgsPoint(x,y)
            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
            if feat_geom.contains(feat.geometry()):
                points.append(feat)
            x += spacing
        y = y - spacing

prov.addFeatures(points)
points_layer.updateExtents()

# Add the layer to the map
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(points_layer)
```

For example, using a high value for the insets (`inset_x = 50` and `inset_y = 30`), I get this result:

[image]

I hope having understood what you want. If you defined an angle instead of two insets, it is easy *translating* it as two length values (I can also edit the answer if you add more specific information about the problem).

Comment: I have the same problem as in creating a grid that is oriented at a certain angle from the north. I have added a rotation angle but end up with just one rotate line of points. Should I create a new post or keep it here, since the original question mentions a rotation?