# Using GIS as a research tool

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, random, suitability-analysis

I am currently doing an assignment and I am using QGIS in order to visualize and assess where wind turbines can go in a specific area. I've done everything that needs to be done to get to this point, i.e., finding suitable land and buffered all the policy restrictions. The only thing is that for the 2D map where I'd need to "place plots", I keep running Random points inside polygons, with my minimum rotor diameter between points. Each time I run this query it randomizes where the points will go, but with various numbers of windmills each time (e.g., 19, 20, 21). It doesn't feel overly scientific if you catch my drift. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Create an ellipse oriented by the main wind direction, size it by the diameter multiplied by the values your organisation agreed on (standard is 5:3), and start copy & pasting those ellipses so they don't overlap the centerpoint of the next one.

Comment: Furthermore, you need to take into account topography and features inside the area you're placing your WTG in. So, yes, you could run this automatically, but the result will be a fantasy-number you can only compare to other, similar fantastic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the number of points generated within each polygon using the [Random Points in Polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgisrandompointsinpolygons) tool, put your desired number of points in the "Number of points for each feature" parameter and specify the "Minimum distance between points" using your rotor diameter. That will ensure that you generate the same number of points every time you run the tool.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your quick answer. Only thing is that I'd like to maximize the amount of points in a given area. Any tips for that?

Comment: @Sarah instead of random points, have you considered using the Create Grid tool? You could set your horizontal and vertical spacing to correspond to you rotor diameter. Without knowing a bit more about your problem I'm not sure that would generate the optimal solution, but it might be more of what you are looking for.

Comment: This is 'bin packaging' problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185889/arcmap-fill-polygon-with-points-highest-possible-number-bin-packing-problem#186025